# Noise Covariance Estimation for Linear Regression (Seemingly Unrelated Regressions)

Tags: covariance, weighted-least-squares

Considering following linear model
\begin{equation}
y_t = X_t f_t + \varepsilon_t, \qquad t=1,\cdots, T
\end{equation}
where $y_t\in\Re^{300\times 1}$ and $X_t\in\Re^{300\times 60}$ are two given sequences for $t=1,\cdots, T$. Error term $\varepsilon_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,Q)$ and $Q$ is a $300\times 300$ unknown diagnal matrix.

I was wondering, is it possible to efficiently estimate the weights $W = Q^{-1}$ or the noise covariance of residuals? so that I could minimise the variance of the $\hat{f}_t$ by solving following weighted linear least squares:
\begin{equation}
\min_{f_t}\|y_t - X_t f_t\|^2_W
\end{equation}

Comment: I use Feasible generalized least squares to estimate the diagnal noise covariance iteratively: [Feasible generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares). It quickly converged within 50 iterations

Comment: Is there any structure on Q? If completely unrestricted, I don’t see how you’d estimate it. A typical strategy is to model Q as a parametric function of the regressors.